# Avoiding (numbering) duplicate keys

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

```
list = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "b" -> 5, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, "c" -> 1, "c" -> 2};
```

In the above example list two keys, `b` and `c`, occur more than once.
To be able to transform it into an `Association`, I want to append an index to the duplicated elements. The sort order of the original list must be preserved.

```
f[list_, r_] :=
 SubsetMap[
  MapIndexed[#1 <> ToString @ First @ #2 &] @ Apply[Table, r]&,
  list,
  Position[list, First @ r]]
```

Repeated keys

```
r = Normal @ Select[# > 1 &] @ Counts @ list[[All, 1]]
```

{"b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}

Wanted result

```
Association @ Fold[f, list, r]
```

<|"a" -> 1, "b1" -> 2, "c1" -> 3, "b2" -> 5, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5,
"c2" -> 1, "c3" -> 2|>

This gets the job done, but I would like to see alternative **functional**
solutions (without loops, counter variables or if-switches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DisambiguateDups[list_] :=
  With[
    {dupCounts = Select[CountsBy[list, Keys], GreaterThan[1]]},
    With[
      {rules = 
         Flatten[Thread /@ 
           KeyValueMap[Position[list, #1] -> StringInsert[ToString /@ Range[#2], #1, 1] &, dupCounts]]},
      ReplacePart[list, rules]]]

DisambiguateDups[list]
(* {"a" -> 1, "b1" -> 2, "c1" -> 3, "b2" -> 5, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, "c2" -> 1, "c3" -> 2} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

```
renameKeys = 
 SubsetMap[ 
    KeyValueMap[Splice @* Map[StringJoin] @* Thread @* List] @*
     ReplaceAll[{{_} -> {""}, x_List :> ToString /@ x}] @* 
     Range @*
     Counts @*
     Sort,
   {All, 1}] @*
 Sort


renameKeys @ list
```

> ```
> {"a" -> 1,   
>  "b1" -> 2, "b2" -> 5,
>  "c1" -> 1, "c2" -> 2, "c3" -> 3,   
>  "d" -> 4,   
>  "e" -> 5}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
resolveKeyCollisions = Module[{$c, counts = Counts @ Keys @ #},
    $c[x_] := Map[ToString] @ Range @ counts @ x;
    $c[_?(counts @ # == 1 &)] = {""};
    SubsetMap[Map[# <> Last[$c[#] = RotateLeft[$c @ #]] &], {All, 1}] @ #] &;

resolveKeyCollisions @ list
```

> ```
> {"a" -> 1, "b1" -> 2, "c1" -> 3, "b2" -> 5,   
>  "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, "c2" -> 1, "c3" -> 2}
> ```

**Original post:**

```
renameDuplicateKeys = Module[{$c}, $c[_] = 0;
  StringReplace[# <> ToString[++$c[#]] & /@ #,  k_ ~~ v_  /; $c[k] == 1 :> k]]&;

SubsetMap[renameDuplicateKeys, list, {All, 1}]
```

> ```
>  {"a" -> 1, "b1" -> 2, "c1" -> 3, "b2" -> 5,   
>   "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, "c2" -> 1, "c3" -> 2}
> ```

Comment: Thank you, kglr, but your answer works with a counter variable (++$c), which I excluded in my question (see its last sentence)

Comment: whoops, missed that. I will update if i find a way without a counter function.

Comment: @eldo, please see the update.

Answer (score 3):

My `DisambiguateDups` version using `GroupBy`:

```
DisambiguateDups[list_] := 
 Association[
  SortBy[Catenate[
     GroupBy[Thread[Range@Length@# -> #] &@list, #[[2, 1]] &, 
      If[Length@# > 1, 
        Cases[Thread[{#[[All, 1]], 
           StringJoin @@@ 
            Thread[{#[[All, 2, 1]], 
              ToString /@ Range[Length@#]}], #[[All, 2, 2]]}], {x_, 
           y_, z_} :> Rule[x, Rule[y, z]]], #] &]], First][[All, 2]]]

DisambiguateDups[list]
```

> <|"a" -> 1, "b1" -> 2, "c1" -> 3, "b2" -> 5, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5,
> "c2" -> 1, "c3" -> 2|>

Answer (score 3):

```
addIndex = MapIndexed[#[[1]] <> ToString[#2[[1]]] -> #[[2]] &];

newKeys = ReplaceAll[r : {_, __} :> addIndex @ r];
```

If it is not essential to keep the ordering of input list, we simply use `newKeys` as the third argument in `GroupBy`:

```
addIndexToDuplicateKeys[] := 
    Association @* Catenate @* Values @* Map[newKeys] @* GroupBy[First]

addIndexToDuplicateKeys[] @ list
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 1, "b1" -> 2, "b2" -> 5, "c1" -> 3, "c2" -> 1, "c3" -> 2, 
>   "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5|>
> ```

If we wish to keep the original ordering we can use the helper functions `addPositions` and `reduceGroups`:

```
addPositions = MapIndexed[Flatten @* List];

reduceGroups = Transpose @* Apply[{newKeys @ #, #2} &] @* Transpose;


addIndexToDuplicateKeys[_ : "KeepOrder"] := 
  Association @* Map[First] @* SortBy[Last] @* Catenate @* Values @*
   Map[reduceGroups] @* GroupBy[#[[1, 1]] &] @* addPositions;

addIndexToDuplicateKeys[blah] @ list
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 1, "b1" -> 2, "c1" -> 3, "b2" -> 5, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, 
>   "c2" -> 1, "c3" -> 2|>
> ```

Comment: Thank you, kglr, I very much like this "destructuring" of the problem. `addIndexToDuplicateKeys` should be preceded with `Association`.

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
f = <|KeyValueMap[
      Splice@Thread[( {k, v} |-> 
       MapIndexed[
         k <> (Boole[Length@v > 1] /. {0 -> "", 1 -> ToString@First@#2}) &]@v )@## -> #2] &
      , Merge[#, Join]][[Ordering[First /@ #]]]|> &;

list = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "b" -> 5, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, "c" -> 1, "c" -> 2};
f@list
```

> <|"a" -> 1, "b1" -> 2, "c1" -> 3, "b2" -> 5, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5,
> "c2" -> 1, "c3" -> 2|>

Answer (score 0):

We can proceed like:

1. we determine the keys that appear more than once and their multiplicity
2. we define counters for all keys
3. then we define a rule that replaces successive keys with new names

   Clear["Global`*"];

   ```
    list = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "b" -> 5, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, 
       "c" -> 1, "c" -> 2};

    mul = Cases[Tally[Keys[list]], {_, n_} /; n > 1][[All, 1]];

    n = Length[mul];

    count = ConstantArray[0, n];

    ru[i_] := mul[[i]] :> Symbol[mul[[i]] <> ToString[++count[[i]]]];

    rules = Table[ru[i], {i, n}];

    list /. rules

    {"a" -> 1, b1 -> 2, c1 -> 3, b2 -> 5, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, c2 -> 1, 
     c3 -> 2}
   ```

P.S. There seems to be something wrong with formatting

Comment: Thank you, Daniel,  but your answer works with a counter variable (++count), which I excluded in my question (see its last sentence)

Comment: The formatting problem seems to be a bug  due to the initial numbering